# HttpRequest not respecting header codes from requested page

Tags: php, httprequest

I'm using the HttpRequest class on a proxy to call an API. I have modifications for caching on the API to throw a 304 if the content has not been modified so that the user making the request can utilize caching.

The API throws a header:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
```

I've confirmed that this is working by inspecting the headers; in firefox a ctrl+shift+r will always return a 200, a ctrl+r after a 200 will always result in the 304. However, on the proxy side the HttpRequest object always returns 200. I've even tried modifying the API so it always throws the 304 no matter what but the proxy still yields 200.

How can I get it to respect the 304 being thrown by the API so I can throw the 304 from the proxy as well?

Comment: What proxy are you using? This sounds like a proxy configuration issue.

Comment: I'm also confused about the purpose of the proxy in regards to your question. But anyway, did you send the `If-Unmodified-Since:` header in your HttpRequest?

Comment: All I'm doing on the proxy is `$request = new HttpRequest($url, $method_type);` (and then the $request->send();) and $method_type is a GET

Comment: Well that's your explanation then. The `HttpRequest` class does not contain any caching logic. It will never receive a 304 if it doesn't send a conditional request.

Comment: What do I need to do to send that If-Unmodified-Since request with HttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

If your caching logic in the API server is correct, then you should really only get a 304 when sending a conditional request like this:

```
$last_request = time() - 60;
    // should be an actual timestamp of cached data!
$last_date = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", $last_request);

$request = new HttpRequest($url, $method_type);
$request->setHeaders(array('If-Unmodified-Since' => $last_date));
$request->send();
```